# If a batter is injured, while hitting a home run out of a park, and cannot physically run the bases, can a pinch runner be used?

Tags: rules, baseball, home-run

If a batter is injured, while hitting a home run out of a park, and cannot physically run the bases, can a pinch runner be used?

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange! Can you please add your actual question to the body text? Right now the title is the only thing providing any information.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRnr6sA7UDQ Gape Kapler was on base when a teammate hit a home run, but fell rounding 2nd base and could not continue. Play was paused, a pinch runner took his place, then play resumed with both runners continuing to home. (The player that hit the home run alertly did not pass Kapler, as that would have resulted in him being called out.)

Answer (score 5):

If a batter-runner is incapacitated during a home run (or any other play where he is entitled to a particular base, such as a walk, a ground rule double, or a ball thrown into the dugout), then his team may use a substitute runner (who then takes his place in the batting order and on the field, unless further replaced).  See the [MLB Official Baseball rules](https://content.mlb.com/documents/2/2/4/305750224/2019_Official_Baseball_Rules_FINAL_.pdf), from rule 5.12:

> When an accident incapacitates a player or an umpire;
>
> > (A) If an accident to a runner is such as to prevent
> > him from proceeding to a base to which he is
> > entitled, as on a home run hit out of the playing
> > field, or an award of one or more bases, a substitute runner shall be permitted to complete the
> > play.